# Which is better, some grids collapsed or some user controls?

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, transition

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7 application that uses some Transient content.

To avoid to go back to that transient content I've decided to use a phew page with several grids on the same page.

When I have to show another "page" I set to collapsed current grid and then I set to visible desired grid.

I know this can be done using user control, but I'm not sure if using user controls can be slowest that using Grids. Any advice?

And another question is if I use grids, how can I use page transitions?

Answer (score 0):

Another option for when you want to show transient content is to use a Popup control.  This won't appear in the navigation stack, so when a user goes back (<-) they won't see this content.

However, Popup content isnt GPU accelerated, so you only want to display simple content, no animations etc...

If you want page transitions etc... then i think your only option is to use Pages.  That way you can do the transitions and the back button works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if you do this via user controls or grids - what matters speed wise is the complexity of your layout.

A user control may be better if you are doing this on a number of pages so you don't repeat yourself.

One way to do page transitions is to do it with stack panels. Have the second "hidden" stack panel way off to the right so it is off screen then animate it in.